# How do I split a single column into multiple columns over multiple rows in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I need to create a stored procedure in SQL Server that accepts the following two parameters:

1. A select statement returning 1 column.
2. A number of columns.

The stored procedure would then run the select statement and return the result of the select statement with the values of the single column split into the given amount of columns per row.

Here are some examples:

```
exec stored_proc ‘select id from table where id between 1 and 20’, 5
```

The result of the select would be:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

The result of the stored procedure call would be:

```
 1            2            3            4            5
 6            7            8            9           10
11           12           13           14           15
16           17           18           19           20
```

Or the call could be:

```
exec stored_proc ‘select id from table where id between 1 and 20’, 10
```

Giving the result of:

```
1              2              3              4              5              6              7              8              9              10
11           12           13           14           15           16           17           18           19           20
```

Comment: I think you're using sql wrong. This is something that probably shouldn't be done using sql, but the language handling it's result. Square pegs, round holes.

Comment: Not to mention they haven't provided any code they've attempted to write to solve their problem.

Comment: Yes, I had the idea come to mind, but I haven't had time to work on a solution yet, so I thought I would throw out the question for responses.

Comment: The application of this code would be a report that produces a detail line for each row returned.  The report can translate each resulting field into whatever (say contact information), but it can't vary the number of fields on each row or the amount of detail lines produced.  That is why I want to do this in a stored proc.  Thank you for the replies so far.

Comment: Do you have any control over, or advanced knowledge of, the query? For example, can you say your query will always return the column as nvarchar(max), or will always be named MyVal? Will your query include an ORDER BY clause?

Comment: At the moment, I am the sole developer in complete control over the queries that are run.  I would like the single column to be a varchar(max) instead of an nvarchar(max).  This stored proc is meant to be generic enough to accept any query, including those with an order by, but that could be altered if there are restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm not sure you should be doing this in SQL, it can be done.
I think the way to do it would be do create a cursor and use it's iterations to build a dynamic SQL statement.

During each iteration, add each piece of data as a new column (field) and when you reach the number of columns add something like `Union Select`